# Encryption Registration Number (ERN) or CCATS required for client/server encryption?

Tags: ios, xcode, encryption, client-server

I want to encrypt communication between iPhone and my server and I will not use SSL for that. Do I still need ERN or CCATS application for that?

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on what type of encryption you are using. What is the level of encryption? Is it open source?

To see whether you need a ERN, please review the following flowchart:

Flow Chart 2: Classifying under an ECCN in Category 5, Part 2

http://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/forms-documents/doc_view/328-flowchart-2

The flowchart will help point you in the right direction in the BIS.

This FAQ is helpful too:

http://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/policy-guidance/encryption/registration